# not able to access firebase in android studio. already updated google play services and copied .json file in java folder

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
>      Searched Location: 
>     F:\android\MyApplication11\app\src\debug\google-services.json
>     F:\android\MyApplication11\app\google-services.json

Comment: Follow the instructions in firebase console. When you create a project it'll prompt you to download a json configuration file that you have to put in your project.

Comment: yes, already done

Comment: Then you put in the the wrong place. It tells you exactly where it expects the file: `F:\android\MyApplication11\app\google-services.json`

Comment: steps has shown that we have to move .json file directly to app folder given at the top, but it is not moving there. can u tell me the exact location?

Comment: The location is the root of the app *module*, typically called 'app'. The exact location is in the error message itself and in my previous comment. You may have to set the project view to 'project' instead of 'android' with the dropdown at the top of the project panel. This shows the actual file tree, and you can find the `app` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Download the google-services.json file from the Firebase Console and place it in the app folder. Make sure name of the file is google-service.json only. No numbers after the file name.

Location for the folder is - F:\android\MyApplication11\app.

Then simply sync again the Gradle file and your problem may be solved.